# If Featured Image On Product Is [image url], Do Something

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can I made if featured image on product is `/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/test.jpg`, add CSS on that image tag?

As example, if featured image is `/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/test.jpg`, it will like this:

```
 <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/test.jpg" style="width: 100px">
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please, Yiedpozi, read [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/185667)

Answer (score 0):

For the simplest case, you need to edit the post thumbnail code (inside the loop obviously) where you want to make this change.

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {

    $image_link  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
    $your_test_image_link = ''; // this is the full url to the test image
    if( $image_link == $your_test_image_link ){
        echo '<img src="'.$image_link.'" style="width:100px">';
    }
    else{
        the_post_thumbnail();
    }
}
```

If you want this to everywhere you might want to hook to the `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes` and place it in the `functions.php` file

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes','23825701_custom_wp_get_attachment_image_attributes');

function 23825701_custom_wp_get_attachment_image_attributes($attr, $attachment){

    $image_link  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment );
    $your_test_image_link = ''; // this is the full url to the test image

    if( $image_link == $your_test_image_link ){
        $attr['style'] = 'width:100px'; // your custom attribute, hence style
        return $attr;
    }
    return $attr;
}
```